# Two user getting control access in socket.io - race condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, race-condition

Two or more users are notified for an available room.

How I am trying to prevent it, and make it so that only one user will be notified available at a time.

```
socket.on('Check', function (room) {

io.in(room).clients((error, clients) => {

    var hasPush = false;

    clients.forEach(function (clientId) {

        var client = io.sockets.connected[clientId];                                      

            if (client.hasPush) {                              

                hasPush = true;                 
                socket.emit('busy', room);
                return;
            }

    }, this);

    if (!hasPush) {
        socket.hasPush = true;                        
        socket.emit('available', room);
    }
  });                                      

});
```

I have tried to prevent using a shared variable but that didn't work.

```
rooms = {};
socket.on('check', function (room) {

    if (!rooms[room]) {
        rooms[room] = true;
    }
    else {
        socket.emit('busy', room);
        return;
    }

    .......

    rooms[room] = false;
}
```

Comment: This is only one server running this right?

Comment: Yes, Only one server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have added two servers with nginx and redis, redis-lock work for me.